# AWS CodeCommit trigger 2 different project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I want to build a trigger or any other way in order that for every change I make in one of the repos in CodeCommit 2 different jobs will be triggered.

Let's say I have repo A,B,C - whenever a change happen on A, I only want to build B, C. 
A is like a src of modules that don't need to be built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a multi source trigger.
Created a pipeline with 2 src, but 1 build. 
Mean 1 pipeline listens to changes in A and B an another to A and C but eventually 1 pipeline is building only B and the other C. A isn't built at all.

In case someone will face that in the future.